# JavaScript - What does these value-assignment (using |= as an operator) mean?

Tags: javascript

Today I have seen these code-snippet:

```
  /**
     * @param src: any variable of any type
     * @param html: output format (true|false); default = false
     * @param level: (internal, don't use)
     *
     * @return string: formatted output
     */
    function showObj(src, html, level) {
      level |= 0;
```

Complete script:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/123283/helper-function-to-format-output-any-type-of-variable

What is the value-assignment with |= ( in "level |= 0" ) ?

I haven't seen it anywhere before and can't find anything about it.

Comment: That's a bitwise `OR` assignment operator. My guess is that it is making sure level is a number??

Comment: It works like `if level exists get his value, if not assign 0 value`. It's an `OR` assignment operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That(`|`) is a [bit wise or operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.7c_%28Bitwise_OR%29), It normally used in situations where the decimal points of a number has to be truncated.

```
var level = 2.444434;
level |= 0; // level = level | 0;
console.log(level) // 2
```

Comment: @ajaprabhu Aravindasamy I think I've got it: It applies a bitwise OR operation using both operands and then assigns the result to the first operand?

Comment: @st88 Yes absolutely. `x | y`  => `to2Base(x) | to2Base(y)` => `to10Base(resultOf2Base)`

Comment: @ajaprabhu Aravindasamy Thanks a bunch. :) Your awesome.

Answer (score 2):

> The bitwise OR assignment operator uses the binary representation of
>   both operands, does a bitwise OR operation on them and assigns the
>   result to the variable.

Live Demo

```js
var bar = 5;
bar |= 2; // 7

alert(bar)
```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Bitwise_OR_assignment)